# Using pointer after free()

Tags: c, linux

During my tests, I have found that it is possible to use pointer after free(). I have the following code:

```
typedef struct{

    int module_id;
    int adc_id;
    struct config_line * pnext;

} config_line;
config_line * create_list()
{

config_line * phead = (config_line *) malloc(sizeof(config_line));
phead->pnext=NULL;
phead->module_id = 1;
phead->adc_id = 2;

printf("module_id=%d adc_id=%d\n",phead->module_id, phead->adc_id);

free(phead);

printf("module_id=%d adc_id=%d\n",phead->module_id, phead->adc_id);

phead->module_id = 2;
phead->adc_id = 5;

printf("module_id=%d adc_id=%d\n",phead->module_id, phead->adc_id);
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
module_id=1 adc_id=2
module_id=0 adc_id=2
module_id=2 adc_id=5
```

Why after free(phead) I can get access (read and write) to pointer? Why there is not segmentation fault?

Comment: Dereferencing a free'd pointer is _undefined behavior_. It will most likely not crash since it's still pointing to some real memory, but the contents may not be what you expect it to be. In short, don't do it!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/12149471) to a corresponding C++ question for an answer which provides a very interesting analogy. At the time of this writing, that answer has received nearly 5000 upvotes. Most of what is said in that answer also applies to C.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because using an invalid pointer invokes undefined behavior. And that means that the behavior is... well... ***undefined.*** It's not **obliged** to crash.

Comment: On Debug builds in VS runtime usually overwrites the memory with something invalid so it's easier to spot errors. It doesn't do it on Release builds though.

Answer (score 16):

When you call `free(phead)`, the memory `phead` points to is being freed, but the value of `phead` stays untouched, making the `phead` a *dangling pointer*. Accessing the memory that has already been freed produces **undefined behavior**.

It is a good practice to assign `NULL` to the pointer once you free the memory it points to:

```
free(phead);
phead = NULL;
```

Comment: assigning NULL ... will not help always, so it is more a obscurity, which may shadow another bug. (head = malloc(); list = head; free(head); head = NULL; => list still points to free'ed memory)

Comment: @PeterMiehle: I'm not saying that assigning `NULL` to the pointer will solve all the problems in the world and all programmers will live happy ever after. I'm just saying it's a good practice how to avoid creation of additional dangling pointers.

Comment: @PeterMiehle What? If you assign `NULL` to `head`, it won't point to `free()`d memory...

Comment: @LihO, I wouldnot say, that it is "good" practice to do so. It is just a sign of "bad" design to have the need to assign a value after shredding the variable. I have seen this "good" practice come to use in "free(x); x=0; return;". A good compiler will complain: "assigning a value without using it afterwards"

Comment: @PeterMiehle: There are situations where assigning `NULL` after memory being `free()`d is perfectly reasonable and intended. Sometimes it's not only a good practice, but a crucial thing to do.

Comment: okay, with "sometimes" and "there are situations" I am perfectly on your side. But when you say "good practice" you (un-)intentionally imply "ALWAYS"; and that is in most cases (oppsed to "sometimes" a false statement. (and btw: do you mean "Not that" or "Note that" in your answer? I personally would stick with the "Not", but I think you mean "Note" :-)

Answer (score 8):

Because the memory is still mapped into your process, but isn't allocated. There are two levels of memory management that go on in a C program: Firstly, the kernel gives you pages you can write to. If the process needs more memory that it has mapped, it has to request more from the kernel (sbrk). That comes in large chunks though, so malloc slices it up into chunks for you, requesting more pages as needed, but using where possible memory already allocated to the program. free can't return a page until all the allocations that used it have been freed.

So, the memory access violations the kernel gives you (SIGSEGV) are rather coarse, and can't pick up most memory errors, only things that are fatal from a kernel point of view. You're free to trash your malloc's tracking data, read past the end of most allocations and after many frees, and so on.

Don't ever commit memory errors though. Run your app with valgrind, which uses a very strict VM, to check for all errors and squash them immediately.

Answer (score 6):

Why might a chicken continue to run and jump around despite it's head being chopped off? Note that this doesn't *always* happen; some chickens might cease moving immediately, while [others might continue to run around for months](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_the_Headless_Chicken). When it does happen, it happens because it happens. Does that mean we should cut our pets heads off?

Like cutting our pets heads off, using memory that has been freed is a bad idea. That doesn't mean it will produce negative results; your program might continue to run as expected on your machine, while `if (fubar)` (where *fubar* is your invalid pointer) might be enough to cause your program to malfunction on *other* implementations.

This idea freedom for the implementation to define (or not) the behaviour is formally known as *undefined behaviour*; the behaviour is undefined because the C standard, a set of documents dictating how C implementations should behave, *doesn't define the behaviour*. Therefore, like cutting our pets heads off, we should avoid *all* undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Because freeing memory (a pointer) just puts back that memory on the free memory pool. The memory doesn't just disappear, and it's contents are not cleaned out till when that memory is allocated again and written to.

So, it is very much possible to access the memory after it's been freed up. Just not a good idea as you can imagine, because it can be allocated anytime, and modified.

Comment: "The memory doesn't just disappear, and it's contents are not cleaned" is not specified by C.  It might be cleared out - it might not.

Answer (score 2):

The data is freed during the `free()` call. Accessing a pointer after calling `free()` gives a so-called "dangling pointer", it's undefined behavior and anything can happen. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486) Specifically, it is UB because of the last sentence of C17 7.22.3.3:

> `void free(void *ptr);`
>
> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined.

In general, there's no magic "erased state" in RAM memories of computers. The values will persist in memory until that cell is used for something else. "Erasing" something merely giving up ownership of those memory cells.

It's good practice to write `NULL` to pointers after calling `free()` for this reason, to mark the pointer as not pointing to anything valid.