# custom function in C doesn't work in Red Hat Linux but yes in HPUX

Tags: c, function, compatibility

I have a function C that simulate the Visual Basic mid function. This code works in HPUX but not in RHEL. For example:

```
main()
{
    char tipo[3];
    char nombre[10];
    strcpy (nombre,"abcdefg");
    strcpy (tipo,lds_mid(nombre,1,2));
    printf ("tipo = %s\n",tipo);
}
```

Results:

HPUX => tipo = "ab"
RHEL => tipo =  (empty)

What is the problem ?

```
char *lds_mid (cadena,inicio,longitud)
    char *cadena; unsigned inicio; unsigned longitud;
{
    int start, length;
    int i;
    char *p;
    int pidio_memoria;

    start = inicio-1;
    length = longitud;
    if (inicio ==0) {
        start = 1;
        length --;
    }
    pidio_memoria = 0;
    for (i=start;(cadena[i]!='\0') && ((i-start)<length);i++) {
        if (i==start) {
            p = (char *) malloc(2*sizeof(char));
            pidio_memoria = -1;
            if (p == NULL) {
                /*printf("\nMemoria agotada\n"); */
                abort();
            }
        }
        else {
            p = (char *) realloc((void *)p,(i-start+ 2)*sizeof(char));
            if (p ==NULL) {
                /*printf("\nMemoria agotada\n"); */
                abort();
            }
        }
        *(p+i-start)=cadena[i];
    } 
    if (pidio_memoria) {
        *(p+i-start) = '\0';

        free(p);
        return p;
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```

Comment: `unsigned inicio; ... = inicio-1` doesn't look nice.

Comment: That's very complicated-looking for what it does. Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: This is pretty horrendous code in terms of flow, structure, comments...

Comment: Don't write K&R code, even on HP-UX.  If you can't afford the HP ANSI C compiler, get GCC installed instead.  Either way, there's no call to write non-prototype functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using pointer after free()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432123/using-pointer-after-free)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
    free(p);
    return p;
```

is instant undefined behavior as soon as the caller uses the returned string pointer.

Here's my attempt:

```
char * lds_mid(const char *string, size_t offset, size_t length)
{
  if(string == NULL)
    return NULL;

  const size_t slen = strlen(string);
  if(offset >= slen)
    return NULL;
  const size_t chunk = offset + length > slen ? slen - offset : length;
  char *out = malloc(chunk + 1);
  if(out != NULL)
  {
    memcpy(out, string + offset, chunk);
    out[chunk] = '\0';
  }
  return out;
}
```

That's about how complicated I would expect such a function to be. There really shouldn't be a need to ever call `realloc()` in this function.

Note that the above gives the caller ownership of the returned string, it must be `free()`d when no longer needed. This means your usage snippet doesn't work, since it drops the returned pointer by passing it to `strcpy()`.

It must be:

```
int main(void)
{
  const char *str = "hello, world!";  /* String to cut part from. */
  char *world = mid(str, 7, 5);
  printf("'%s' ends with '%s'\n", str, world);
  free(world);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing `p` before you return to main(). Specifically the issue is here:

```
if (pidio_memoria) {
*(p + i - start) = '\0';

//free (p);
return p;
```

Once you have gotten rid of the `free(p)`, you function produces output:

```
tipo = ab
```

Good luck.